# What is a tagDone?

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page

In Tag watching & ignoring, there is a link to "Add a tagDone". Seems a bit weird for a name.
(Safari on macOS Sonoma beta)

[image: "Add a tagDone" in Tag watching & ignoring]

Comment: Looks like there's some whitespace missing

Comment: Same with [ruSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onwWb.png).

Comment: Just like updog.

Comment: It looks like [both buttons are showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4CWq.png) where only one should be visible at a time. [They both work as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXVkA.gif), but it seems like it should show "Add a tag" on page load and then switch to "Done" only after you click the "Add a tag" button.